# Gateway Timeout when performing REST API CALL via Python3.9

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to query [this site](https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=EQUITASBNK) for historical price volume data, but it seems my GET queries are timing out. How can I set up my requests to bypass this problem?

The way the code is set up is:

1. The landing page of the ticker that I want to download historical data for (here EQUITASBNK), is first queried
2. I extract the cookie for the response I receive
3. I use this cookie and modified parameters to (try to extract) the historical data

Step 1 -> Status 200
Step 3 -> Code hangs/Stuck waiting for response

This is my code:

```
class NSE(Exchange):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url_landing = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?"
        self.url_quotes ="https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?"

    def fetchbulkprices(self, ticker, fromdate, todate):
          sys.stderr.write("Querying Ticker = {} fromdate = {} todate {} \n".format(ticker, fromdate, todate))
          headers = {
            "authority": "www.nseindia.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=" + ticker + "&series = [%22EQ%22]&from=" + fromdate + "&to="+ todate+ "&csv=true",
           "scheme": "https",
           "accept": "*/*",
           "accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
           "referer": "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol="+ticker,
           "sec-ch-ua": "Google Chrome" + ";" + "v=""111"", ""Not(A:Brand""" + ";" + "v=""8""" + ",""Chromium""",
           "sec-ch-ua-mobile" : "?0",
           "sec-ch-ua-platform" : "Windows",
           "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
           "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
           "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
           "x -requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
           }
         session = requests.Session()
         params = {"symbol": ticker}
         response = requests.get(self.url_landing, params=params, headers=headers)
        cookies = response.cookies
        params = {"symbol": ticker, "series": "[%22EQ%22]", "fromDate": from date,"toDate": todate, "csv": True}
        response = session.get(self.url_quotes, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        if response.status_code == 200:
          sys.stderr.write("Queried successfully")
```

A few sample queries can be (Symbol, From Date, To Date):

1. AAVAS, 18-09-2020, 23-01-2021
2. EQUITASBNK, 18-09-2020, 23-01-2021
3. MASTEK, 18-09-2020, 23-01-2021

Comment: Hi Soham, could you fix the indexing of your function(s) so it is more readable which part of code belongs where?

Comment: Done. Hopefully this reads better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AAVAS, 18-09-2020, 23-01-2021

The bad news is that you cannot use the desired range - nseindia API does not let you query data older than 2 years from now:

```json
{"error":true,"showMessage":"Please select date range not more than 2 Years."}
```

However the good news is that you still can obtain historical data using plain HTTP requests. Here is simple example to obtain historical data for `AAVAS` ticker:

```py
import requests

HEADERS = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}


def find_ticker_historical_info(ticker: str, from_: str, to_: str) -> None:
    with requests.Session() as sess:
        # get a root page to get and save cookies necessary for other requests
        _ = sess.get('https://www.nseindia.com/', headers=HEADERS)
        
        # obtain hist data for a ticker
        r = sess.get(
            'https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity',
            headers=HEADERS,
            params={'symbol': ticker, 'from': from_, 'to': to_}
        )
        if not r.ok:
            print(r.status_code)
            print(r.text)
        else:
            print(r.json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_ticker_historical_info('AAVAS', from_='24-01-2021', to_='23-01-2023')
```

Comment: Hi @Ivan - thank you for the response. The fromdate- todate range cannot be longer than 2 years - I figured my problem was wrong parameters. It doesn't respond/react well to csv = True. Also my "fromdate" parameter is not recognised by the server. Thank you!